# tomcat7 host manager does not add new domain as a host- "Failed to create AppBase"

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7

I have installed Tomcat7 in my Ubuntu 12.04 x64 VPS.

Now I am trying to add a new domain via HostManager.

However, this is the error I am getting--

```
    FAIL - Failed to create appBase [/var/lib/tomcat7/domain.com] for host [domain.com]
```

I even created a custom folder--> set its permissions to 777, and then gave that folder as the App Base Path for the new domain(in Host Manager)-- however even then I am getting the same error message as above.

What am I doing wrong here? How do I add the new domain correctly in Tomcat7 Host Manager?

Answer (score 1):

I updated tomcat6 (which allowed me to add virtual hosts in HostManager without any problems) to tomcat7 and had the same problem.

FAIL - Failed to create appBase [/var/lib/tomcat7/xxx] for host [xxx]

By creating the directory (/var/lib/tomcat7/xxx) and changing ownership and group to tomcat7 it worked and I could set up the virtual host xxx. 
I am just getting back into tomcat after several years absence, so not trying to give a complete answer. Probably differences between tomcat6 and tomcat7 in where the config files want data to be stored. Original automatic ubuntu 12.04 install sorted this out, but now have to figure it out!

Answer (score 0):

set 777 permissions to tomcat folder (eg.)

```
chmod 777 /var/lib/tomcat8/
```

Answer (score 0):

Add permission in server.xml file and save.u can refer tomcat information which is given by them in first page after it shows success ! And click all button in host manager